# Find all IP addresses from array

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

I have a lot of arrays which looks like

```
$a = 'Handshake', 'Success', 'Status', 200, '192.30.253.113', 'OK', 0xF
```

Information contained in this array may be different but there are IP addresses always in it (one or more, maximum three). I looking for a way for extract these addresses from array(s). What is the simplest way to do it? I ask your attention that position of IP addresses in arrays is various.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a.Where{!($_ -as [Double]) -and $_ -as [IPAddress]}
```

Or if you wanna be sure that IP addresses are valid use regular expression shown by @JulienNury

Comment: Should be checked as answer as it also detects IPv6 addresses. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp may be the fastest way:

```
$a -match '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'
```

Comment: Very useful for me! Air kiss.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have multiple arrays such as `$a`, `$b`, `$c` etc. you can use a regular expression as such -

```
$arr = @()
$pattern = "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

$a, $b, $c | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
           $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
            }
        }
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value.Trim()}
```

Now you `$arr` will have all the IP addressess from all the multiple arrays.